# PyQt4 QMessageBox text change

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using this simple code to show warning boxes:

```
w = QWidget() 
result = QMessageBox.warning(w, 'a', x, QMessageBox.Ok)
```

Is there any way to change MESSAGE dynamically? I want to make a popup which will inform user abut progress of a task that is running in background.

Edit:

Well I tried to do so making this script for testing:

```
def handleButton(self):
        self.msgBox = QMessageBox(self)
        self.msgBox.setWindowTitle("Title")
        self.msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        self.msgBox.setText("Start")
        self.msgBox.show()
        x = 0
        for x in range (100):
            x = x + 1
            print (x)
            self.msgBox.setText(str(x))
            self.msgBox.show()
            time.sleep(1)
```

The text only shows after finishing the 'for loop', why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a static method you could create an object of the class.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.msgBox = QMessageBox(self)
        self.msgBox.setWindowTitle("Title")
        self.msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        self.msgBox.setText("Start")
        self.msgBox.show()

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)
        timer.start(1000)

    def onTimeout(self):
        self.msgBox.setText("datetime: {}".format(QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update:**

The problem in your example is the use of `time.sleep()`. Qt is executed in an eventloop, this eventloop allows you to handle the events of the mouse, keyboard, redraw, etc. but the `time.sleep()` blocks the eventloop, this you can check trying to change the size of the window, you will see that you can not do it.

Assuming you use `time.sleep()` to pause, then you must use `QEventLoop` with `QTimer` that does not block the Qt eventloop.

```
def handleButton(self):
    self.msgBox = QMessageBox(self)
    self.msgBox.setWindowTitle("Title")
    self.msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
    self.msgBox.setText("Start")
    self.msgBox.show()

    for x in range(100):
        self.msgBox.setText(str(x+1))
        loop = QEventLoop()
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, loop.quit)
        loop.exec_()
```

Comment: @PiotrKołtan look at my update, If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.